# Typescript complains when I try to postMessage back to source

Tags: typescript

This is my code

```
window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  e.source.postMessage('hi there, I hear you!', '*');
});
```

This is the error:

> [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((message: any, targetOrigin: string, transfer?: any[]) => void) | ((message: any, transfer?: any[]) => void)' has no compatible call signatures.

When I inspect `postMessage` it seems to be a method on `window` and have the signature:

```
declare function postMessage(
    message: any,
    targetOrigin: string,
    transfer?: any[]
): void;
```

That looks very much like my call signature to me. So what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I found the solution here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26403. For Christmas I wish for TypeScript to give better error messages!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`e.source` is of type `MessageEventSource`.

`type MessageEventSource = WindowProxy | MessagePort | ServiceWorker;`

Since only `WindowProxy` has the method signature you're using, you can guard it with:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  if (!(e.source instanceof MessagePort) && !(e.source instanceof ServiceWorker)) {
    e.source.postMessage('hi there, I hear you!', '*');
  }
});
```

Or somehow else tell the TS that your `e.source` is of type `WindowProxy | Window`.

Comment: anyway to test if it's WindowProxy directly? `event.source instanceof Window` does not work for me

Comment: you dont need to check it with an if statement, that brings complexity into your code without any benefit (besides type checking)
You can just do 
```(e.source as WindowProxy).postMessage('my message');
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is correct, however you're risking crashing in not-so-old browsers that do not support [`MessagePort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessagePort) or [`ServiceWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker) yet. You could check if `MessagePort` and `ServiceWorker` exist in the global space using `typeof`, but that's not good enough for TypeScript static validator. Also it makes the condition complicated unnecessarily.

As alternative I propose checking against Window, which does exist in all browsers and prevents crashing in not-so-old browsers. Event#source can also be null, so that's also implicit in the new condition. And it's just better.

```
window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  if (!(e.source instanceof Window)) return;

  // Use normally.
  e.source.postMessage('hi there, I hear you!', '*');
});
```